# Bitwise operations - get the next char in ASCII table

Tags: java, char, ascii, bit

How can I write a program that will use bitwise operation to take the next value in the ASCII table?

`Input:` char from ASCII table
`Output:` the next char from the ASCII table.

For example, if I get 'a' as input, the program should return 'b'.

If I get '7' as input, the program should return '8'. and so on...

Comment: Why to use bitwise operation to do that?

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342042/why-this-code-for-additionusing-bitwise-operation-works-in-java

Answer (score 7):

Just add 1 (character can be treated as being int16):

```
 char value = 'a';

 char next = (char) (value + 1); // <- next == 'b'
```

Comment: Also needs to mention that ASCII is 7bit or 0-127 values, while Java chars are Unicode 16bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just Increment by 1.

```
Input  = 'a';
Output = ++Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Just cast your char as an int.

```
char character = 'a';    
int ascii = (int) character;
```

and then you need to add 1 in `ascii`

```
 ++ascii;
```

and convert it back...

```
char c=(char)ascii ;
System.out.println(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that will add 1 to its argument using only bit-wise functions.

```
public void test() {
  String s = "Hello";
  StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder(s.length());
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    t.append((char) inc(s.charAt(i)));
  }
  System.out.println(s);
  System.out.println(t.toString());
}

private int inc(int x) {
  // Check each bit 
  for (int i = 0; i < Integer.SIZE; i++) {
    // Examine that bit
    int bit = 1 << i;
    // If it is zero
    if ((x & bit) == 0) {
      // Set it to 1
      x |= bit;
      // And stop the loop - we have added one.
      break;
    } else {
      // Clear it.
      x &= ~bit;
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

prints

```
Hello
Ifmmp
```