# Java bitwise operations return "wrong" value

Tags: java, binary, operations

---EDIT: I am not allowed to use any packages, or prewirtten methods. And no worries, i don't want you to make my "homework", i just need a little hint!---
I found [these interesting Algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895173/bitwise-multiply-and-add-in-java). I want to use the method bitwiseAdd. My problem is, that the left shift operator returns a value that is not binary...
I understand the algorithm, but i am quite a beginner. So here is the "program". I implemented extra outputs to find the issue. I think it must be the left shift operator. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Addition1
{
public static int first;
public static int second;
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{

    BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Geben sie den ersten Summanden ein!");
    first = Integer.parseInt(userInput.readLine());
    System.out.println("Geben sie den zweiten Summanden ein!");
    second = Integer.parseInt(userInput.readLine());
    bitwiseAdd(first, second);
}

public static void bitwiseAdd(int n1, int n2)
{
    int x = n1, y = n2;
    int xor, and, temp;
    and = x & y;
    xor = x ^ y;
    System.out.println("x: " + x);
    System.out.println("y: " + y);
    System.out.println("and: " + and);
    System.out.println("xor: " + xor);
    System.out.println("Schleife:");
    while (and != 0)
    {
        and <<= 1;
        System.out.println("and <<= 1: " + and);
        temp = xor ^ and;
        System.out.println("temp = xor ^ and: " + temp);
        and &= xor;
        System.out.println("and &= xor: " + and);
        xor = temp;
        System.out.println("xor = temp: " + xor);
    }
    System.out.println("Ergebnis: " + xor);
}
}
```

Here is the output (+annotations) of the program for n1= 1001 and n2=1101:

```
Geben sie den ersten Summanden ein! (means: type in first value)
1001
Geben sie den zweiten Summanden ein! (means: type in second value)
1101
x: 1001
y: 1101
and: 73 (java might interpret x and y as non binary)
xor: 1956
Schleife: (means: loop)
and <<= 1: 146
temp = xor ^ and: 1846
and &= xor: 128
xor = temp: 1846
and <<= 1: 256
temp = xor ^ and: 1590
and &= xor: 256
xor = temp: 1590
and <<= 1: 512
temp = xor ^ and: 1078
and &= xor: 512
xor = temp: 1078
and <<= 1: 1024
temp = xor ^ and: 54
and &= xor: 1024
xor = temp: 54
and <<= 1: 2048
temp = xor ^ and: 2102
and &= xor: 0
xor = temp: 2102
Ergebnis: 2102 (means: result)
```

I would be happy about any help! :)
Have a nice day,
Cortex

Comment: What do you mean by "returns a value that is not binary"?

Comment: If you want to _parse_ your numbers as binary, you can use `Integer.parseInt(yourString, 2)`

Comment: @iamnotmaynard well, for 1001 & 1101 there should be the result 1001 and not 73..

Comment: When you print an int, Java outputs the decimal representation. Likewise, Integer.parseInt assumes the input is in decimal. That might be your point of confusion.

Comment: @fge yeah, i know. But this is a "homework", don't worry. I have done the algorithm on paper before, then googled for it.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard oh, i understand. Is there any way i can solve this problem? Using another input method? I'd like to make it look "good", so without an console input that looks like: java Addition1 1001 1101

Answer (score 2):

The values in your program were never interpreted as binary.  You are actually adding the decimal values `1001` and `1101`, and correctly summing them to `2102`.  Also, the binary representations of decimal `1001` and `1101` are

```
1001: 00000011 11101001
1101: 00000100 01001101
```

When `and`ed, you get decimal `73`:

```
  73: 00000000 01001001
```

If you want to interpret those numbers as binary, use a radix of `2` in [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-), for example:

```
first = Integer.parseInt(userInput.readLine(), 2);
```

To output a number in a binary format, use [`Integer.toBinaryString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-), for example:

```
System.out.println("Ergebnis: " + Integer.toBinaryString(xor));
```

Comment: I am very sorry for the misconception! I am not allowed to use the method Integer.toBinaryString.

Comment: @Cortex - well write an equivalent yourself.  And a method that converts a binary string to an integer.  (But I suspect that you are over elaborating the assignment requirements and/or the constraints.  I really don't think that your teacher is say that you cannot use *any* standard Java library methods or classes.  If he is, then you cannot use `println` !!!)

Comment: @StehenC Well that might be the case.. i used first = 1001;
        second = 1101;
        bitwiseAdd(first, second); in the main method, but still the program interprets these as decimal numbers (which is logical). Do you know how i can change that?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write a virtual machine inside a virtual machine inside the real machine, which might itself be a virtual machine.  No wonder there is confusion.

You will need to represent you data as array of bool (or int or char etc).

```
bool [] operand1 = new bool [8];
bool [] operand2 = new bool [8];

bool [] leftShift (bool [] operand)
{
    bool [] result = new bool [operand.length];

    for (int i=8; i>1; i++)
    {
        result[i] = operand[i-1];
    }
    return result;
}

bool [] and (bool [] operand1, bool [] operand2)
{
     int max, min;
     if (operand1.length > operand2.length) {
          max = operand1.length;
          min = operand2.length;
     }
     else {
          max = operand2.length;
          min = operand1.length;
     }
     bool [] result = new bool [max];

     for (int i = 0; i<min;i++)
     {
         result[i] = operand1[i] && operand2[i];
     }
     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I used `first = 1001; second = 1101; bitwiseAdd(first, second);` in the main method, but still the program interprets these as decimal numbers (which is logical).

When you write a literal in a Java program, the syntax of the literal tells Java how to interpret it.

```
12345     // decimal
012345    // octal
0x1234    // hexadecimal
0b1001    // binary
```

There is no guesswork here.  The syntax you use tells the Java compiler.

For more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

(The only slightly tricky thing is that a leading non-significant zero means that the number is octal not decimal.  That is an regrettable (IMO) carry-over from the C programming language.  It does trip up some people.)

> Do you know how i can change that?

Yea ... if you want to express the numbers as binary in the source code, use binary literals.

---

The thing you need to get thoroughly into your head is that binary / octal / decimal / hexadecimal are all about getting numbers from or presenting numbers to the user (or programmer).  Internally, they all turn into the same thing.  The `int` type (and other integral types) are *agnostic* of decimal, binary and so on.  There is only one type, and the arithmetic and bitwise operators on `int` have only one meaning.