# Multiplying user input by only using addition

Tags: java

I have to create a code that can ask the user to enter 2 numbers and then multiple those numbers, but only by using addition (sum)

I was told I had to use a loop to do this code, but I can't figured out how to tell the loop to iterate number1 by number2 (or vice versa). I'm kind of lost.

This is what I have so far

```
int number1;
int number2;
int i;
int product;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
number1 = input.nextInt();

Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter another number: ");
number2 = input2.nextInt();
```

Comment: Do you remember how multiplication was explained in elementary school?

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop? Then, instead of using a condition like `i < 10` replace the 10 by the number of times (iterations) you need.

Comment: You mean instead of 10, I use number1 instead?

Comment: Well, I don't know if you have to iterate over `number1` or `number2`, but yes, that's the *solution*.

Comment: The way I thought to do it was iterating number1 by the amount of number2 or vice versa. Then, equal the product to that iteration and then printing product. So, if the user entered 4 and 5, it should repeat the 4 five times... printing 20.

Comment: check this answer with bitwise multiplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895173/bitwise-multiply-and-add-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ( i = 0; i < number1; i++)
    product += number2;
```

It's adding x of y times or y of x times.
You should have learned at school.

Comment: Yeah, man.. thanks. I got confused about the condition. Never occurred to me it was possible to use it like that -_-

Answer (score 1):

In java, you can use variables as iteration limits.

eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number2; i++) {
    // your addition code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number1; i++) {
    product = product + number2;
}
```

or this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number2; i++) {
    product = product + number1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem at the end was very simple. It's amazing how I was breaking my head trying to figure out this. Thanks for the explaining :)